# Using System.Attribute class

Tags: c#, reflection, code-reuse

I got myself in a situation where using the System.Attribute class seemed (at first glance) to be a good idea.

I have an object to be printed in my application, and I need a label before each property (or just a string before it). I could put each property hardcoded like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Color:"+obj.color);
Console.WriteLine("Size:"+obj.size);
```

And so on for each property. But instead of it, I was trying to create a code where this 'label' doesn't needed to be hardcoded, so I could print every property dynamically.

I got something like that, using System.Attribute class:

```
public class MyObject 
{
    [MyCustomLabel("Color:")]
    public string Color;

    [MyCustomLabel("Size:")]
    public string Size;
    //etc...
}
```

So here comes my problem: retrieving this Attribute's value is not impossible, but it's not friendly since I had to use some reflection for it.

I'm not really scared of using reflection, but it seemed that I was using attributes for something that it wasn't created for.

I wonder where are the best places for using attributes, and if this is really a situation for using it.

Comment: What are you going to do when someone asks you to ship a French version of your application?  Put user-facing "magic strings" into resources so that you can easily pull them out and localize them, not into attributes where they are "baked in" to the metadata.

Comment: Some more thoughts on properties vs attributes: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/02/properties-vs-attributes.aspx

Comment: Why don't you like reflection?

Comment: I don't understand Eric Lippert's comment.  Attributes can also use localizable resources: for example the internal System.Windows.Forms.SRDescriptionAttribute, which inherits from System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute, gets a string from resources.

Comment: Sure. But why go through all that rigamarole?  What does it buy you?

Comment: Eric Lippert: Actually, I thought about multi-language too. I'm using the magic strings just like you said.

Jay Bazuzi: Not that I don't like reflection, I like it a lot (but still beggining with it on C#). What I thought is: if isn't there a coder-friendly way to retrive the Attributes, maybe they were not meant to be retrieved. 
But I liked what Scott Weinstein said: Attributes and reflection go hand in hand. So I'll check more about them thinking on this approach

Comment: Or maybe I didn't find the right way to retrieve them =)

Comment: "But why go through all that rigamarole? What does it buy you?" - Ask the .NET team that implemented it.  In their case I suspect it was mainly so that intellisense in the VS properties window could display localized descriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attributes and reflection go hand in hand. With the exception of some compiler/runtime attributes, there's no way to use them with out reflecting over the code.

That said, your approach is reasonable, and you might want to take a look at the attributes in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace which have a number of classes to decorate properties with useful metadata.

Comment: Hmm interesting set of classes! I'm taking a look into it. thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

Also, there is a [DisplayName] attribute already tailor-made for this purpose, which has been in .NET since 2.0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're just writing to the console, i.e. it's debugging style output then what you want is minimal chance of typo/copy paste error.

This is confusing under the hood but is highly effective at the call sites:

```
public static void WriteNameAndValue<T,TValue>(
    this TextWriter tw, T t,
    Expression<Func<T, TValue>> getter)
{
    var memberExpression = getter.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("missing body!");
    var member = memberExpression.Member;
    tw.Write(member.Name);
    tw.Write(": ");
    if (member is FieldInfo)
    {
        tw.Write(((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(t));
    }
    else if (member is PropertyInfo)
    {
        tw.Write(((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(t, null));
    }
}


public static void WriteNameAndValueLine<T,TValue>(
    this TextWriter tw, T t,
    Expression<Func<T, TValue>> getter)
{

    WriteNameAndValue<T,TValue>(tw, t, getter);
    tw.WriteLine();
}
```

then you can write

```
t.Foo = "bar";
t.Bar = 32.5;
Console.Out.WriteNameAndValueLine(t, x => x.Foo);
Console.Out.WriteNameAndValueLine(t, x => x.Bar);
// output
// Foo: bar
// Bar: 32.5
```

If you want this to be more configurable at runtime via resources and with considerations for localization you can do so but I would consider another, more standardized, approach instead if this was a likely requirement.

P.S. if you wanted to get fancy you could replace the FieldInfo/PropertyInfo switch with

```
tw.Write(getter.Compile()(t));
```

and then you could check for MethodInfo in the expression as well (or allow arbitrary lambdas and just insert the line number or some other generic text. I suggest not going down this route, the usage is already confusing also this may cause unwanted load in what should be a simple logging method.

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly how Serialization works so I would say your approach is reasonable. Another way you can approach this is to create a dictionary of PropertyNames and their Titles and then look up the title based on the property name.

Answer (score 0):

> > I have an object to be printed in my application, and I need a label before each property (or just a string before it).

Why do you think of using attributes in your case? Where do you print this objects in your application.

Maybe just implement **ToString** in your object(s)
E.g.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("PropertyX: ");
    sb.AppendLine(this.PropertyX);

    // get string from resource file
    sb.Append(Resources.FileName);
    sb.Append(": ");
    sb.AppendLine(this.FileName);

    sb.Append("Number: ");
    sb.AppendLine(this.Number.ToString());

    return sb.ToString();
}
```